# rearrange a vector with specific skip pattern in r

Tags: r, permutation

I have a result from permutation as below;

```
abc <- gtools::permutations(4,3,repeats.allowed = T)
```

I am trying to rearrange this response so that the vector `abc[,1]` remains as it is but vector `abc[,2]` and `abc[,3]` should be as follows;

`abc[,2]` should be rearranged to  `1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4`

`abc[,3]` should be rearranged to `1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 4 3 4 3 4 3 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly manual, so not sure if you are looking for a more automated sorting approch:

```
abc[,2] <- rep(rep(1:4, each = 2), length.out = nrow(abc))
abc[,3] <- rep(c(rep(1:2, 2), rep(3:4, 2)), length.out = nrow(abc))
```

gives:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    2
 [3,]    1    2    1
 [4,]    1    2    2
 [5,]    1    3    3
 [6,]    1    3    4
 [7,]    1    4    3
 [8,]    1    4    4
 [9,]    1    1    1
[10,]    1    1    2
[11,]    1    2    1
[12,]    1    2    2
[13,]    1    3    3
[14,]    1    3    4
[15,]    1    4    3
[16,]    1    4    4
[17,]    2    1    1
[18,]    2    1    2
[19,]    2    2    1
[20,]    2    2    2
[21,]    2    3    3
[22,]    2    3    4
[23,]    2    4    3
[24,]    2    4    4
[25,]    2    1    1
[26,]    2    1    2
[27,]    2    2    1
[28,]    2    2    2
[29,]    2    3    3
[30,]    2    3    4
[31,]    2    4    3
[32,]    2    4    4
[33,]    3    1    1
[34,]    3    1    2
[35,]    3    2    1
[36,]    3    2    2
[37,]    3    3    3
[38,]    3    3    4
[39,]    3    4    3
[40,]    3    4    4
[41,]    3    1    1
[42,]    3    1    2
[43,]    3    2    1
[44,]    3    2    2
[45,]    3    3    3
[46,]    3    3    4
[47,]    3    4    3
[48,]    3    4    4
[49,]    4    1    1
[50,]    4    1    2
[51,]    4    2    1
[52,]    4    2    2
[53,]    4    3    3
[54,]    4    3    4
[55,]    4    4    3
[56,]    4    4    4
[57,]    4    1    1
[58,]    4    1    2
[59,]    4    2    1
[60,]    4    2    2
[61,]    4    3    3
[62,]    4    3    4
[63,]    4    4    3
[64,]    4    4    4
```

Comment: you are right I was thinking of an automated way of looking at it. Because with what I am doing I would want to extend the idea to something like `abc <- gtools::permutations(9,3,repeats.allowed = T)` for which `abc[,2] <- rep(rep(1:9, each = 3), length.out = nrow(abc))` the other column should be `abc[,3] <- rep(c(rep(1:3, 3), rep(4:6, 3), rep(7:9, 3)), length.out = nrow(abc))`. Any ideas on how I would automate everything?

Comment: The pattern on how to extend with each new element is clear if you look at it. The comlicated thing is to extend it across columns because then you‘d also haven abc[,4] etc.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Why do you need thi sorting pattern? Maybe there‘s an entirely different way of getting your desired result.

Comment: with what I am doing the only thing that changes in `n` in  `gtools::permutations(n=9,r=3,repeats.allowed = T)` but `r` will always be 3. In other words `n` can be 4 or 9 or something else but r will always be 3. Therefore abc[,4] is not possible. All I need is the kind of arrangement exactly as you have it your output above. I was thinking of `expand.grid()` but it wouldn't sort it accordingly. As an example if I would sort `expand.grid(c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4),c(1,2,3,4))` to obtain your results of `abc` above then that would work

Comment: THe question was more why you need this permutation pattern? What kind of analysis do you want to do and why is it important to have this specific pattern of sorting? I'm skeptical if it is necessary, also because when you do permutations you'll have each combination two times, and I guess you don't want to run your things several times for each pattern.

Comment: Yet another question: how do you want to arrange abc[,3] in case of an odd-number case e.g. with n=9? Would it then be 121212123434343456565656787878789999 or 1212121234343434[repeated 9 times]5656565678787878[repeated 9 times]9999[repeated 9 times]?